# Why can't I use the same generic type with inherited interface?

Tags: c#

HI,
I have the following scenario which I will try to explain as best as I can, appologies in advance if this is a silly question.
I have two interfaces ( for the purposes of this example have nothing in them)

```
public interface interfaceA {}
public interface interfaceB: interfaceA {}
```

And 2 classes

```
public classA<interfaceA> {}
public classB: classA<interfaceB> { }
```

Now also elsewhere I have a method which accepts the generic type as a param :

```
public static void DoSomething( ClassA<interfaceB> p_val ) {}
```

Ok then i consume these classes when creating my objects.

```
ClassB obj1 = new ClassB();
ClassA<interfaceA> obj2 = new ClassA<interfaceA>();
```

Ok all fine when I pass obj1 into DoSomething() now but when I try to pass obj2 into my DoSomething() method, i get a compilation error saying it cannot convert from interfaceA to interfaceB.

This kind of make sense since in my method, the generic param type is explicitly interfaceB. However if i want the method to accept both generic types ( obj1 and obj2), what should I do? hopefully this make sense.

Comment: Where are the interfaces being used? And could you use the code markup to make your code stuff a bit more readable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about

```
public static void DoSomething<T>( ClassA<T> p_val)
{}
```

This accepts any instance of ClassA no matter what the type argument is. Or if you only want to accept instance of `ClassA<T>` when `T` is `InterfaceA` or a subclass thereof, you can do:

```
public static void DoSomething<T>( ClassA<T> p_val) where T : InterfaceA
{}
```

Answer (score 4):

[sepp2k](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158671/why-cant-i-use-the-same-generic-type-with-inherited-interface/3158723#3158723) and [Jordão](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158671/why-cant-i-use-the-same-generic-type-with-inherited-interface/3158736#3158736) both provide the solution to your problem. As for the reason *why* (per your question title) ...

Before .NET 4.0, [covariance and contravariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29) were not allowed in generics - you're trying to use contravariance (going from a wider base class to a narrower subclass). It would be like specifying a `classA<object>` to a method expecting a `classA<string>`.

Whatever `ClassA` does with `interfaceB`, you cannot guarantee obj2 will be able to fulfill it, because obj2 *doesn't handle `interfaceB` instances* (nor, implicitly, do its consumers). It only works with `interfaceA` instances.

If you're using 4.0, you can do this in a limited fashion with interfaces and delegates. See [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Jeff I agree, once I have it in the method I guess it depends what I then want do with it in which I case I assume  covariance and contravariance could become an issue?

Comment: Exactly - it's definitely worth investigating, since whether or not it's a problem depends on why `DoSomething` requires a `ClassA<interfaceB>` (rather than something more general) and what it's consumers do with it.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies, definetly helps my understanding of c#.

Answer (score 2):

There's a misunderstanding here:

```
public class classA<interfaceA> {}
```

This is NOT `interfaceA`, it's a type parameter with the same name as `interfaceA`. Try it like this and the error will make sense:

```
public class classA<T> {}
```

Maybe this is what you really intended:

```
public class classA<T> where T : interfaceA {}
```

But it still won't work in your example without the change proposed by [sepp2k](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158671/why-cant-i-use-the-same-generic-type-with-inherited-interface/3158723#3158723).

Answer (score 1):

Well the smallest common unit is interface A, so try declare the interface A param instead of B in the DoSomthing Method.